# Cannot get passed customer details on checkout

Tags: expresso-store

After upgrading to v2 we can no longer get passed the customer details section of this site https://www.baileysfurniture.com. No errors at all. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean you can't get from `/checkout/details` to `/checkout/confirm`? I was able to do that without a problem. I did see a JS error, but doesn't seem like it would be one that prevented moving from customer details to order confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

It's failing silently but it's most likely down to a missing or invalid field value somewhere in the checkout. If you remove `error_handling="inline"` from your `exp:store:checkout` tag it will fall back to default EE error handling and you should be able to see specifics of what the cause of the problem is.